# Iterate through hash, return all values on one line as a string

Tags: ruby, hash, loops

I have the following hash:

```
{"a"=>2, "d"=>5, "f"=>1, "g"=>1, "h"=>1, "i"=>1, "z"=>2}
```

In ruby, how do you iterate through the hash to display `a2d5f1g1h1i1z2`

Comment: Be aware that hash order isn't guaranteed in Ruby versions earlier than 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to iterate. `Array#join` will work recursively, and `flatten` is not necessary.

```
{"a"=>2, "d"=>5, "f"=>1, "g"=>1, "h"=>1, "i"=>1, "z"=>2}.to_a.join
# => a2d5f1g1h1i1z2

require 'benchmark'
h = {"a"=>2, "d"=>5, "f"=>1, "g"=>1, "h"=>1, "i"=>1, "z"=>2}
n = 1000000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('to_a'){n.times{h.to_a.join}}
  x.report('flatten'){n.times{h.flatten.join}}
end

      user     system      total        real
to_a  5.510000   0.000000   5.510000 (  5.509186)
flatten  6.200000   0.000000   6.200000 (  6.219246)
```

Comment: ...but if you did want to: `hash.each{ |k,v| print k,v }`

Comment: I am returned with a no method error. I'm using ruby 1.9.2, and this is object is an instance of the Hash class.

Comment: Don't you need a flatten in there?

Comment: @JZ I use 1.9.2. It should work, but try the other one that I added. @Wes It worked on mine witout flatten. Ruby 1.9.2. But since I can't test 1.9.1 or lower, I added it anyway.

Comment: I must need to update my 1.9.2. ruby-1.9.2-p136, does not work for some reason. Thanks for your help and the obvious suggestion!

Comment: @JZ You can actually get ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909), which is what I have.

Comment: @JZ Sorry, `Hash#join` on my previous answer was due to an external library. But `Array#join` will work recursively, and `flatten` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple:

```
> {"a"=>2, "d"=>5, "f"=>1, "g"=>1, "h"=>1, "i"=>1, "z"=>2}.flatten.join
 => "a2d5f1g1h1i1z2"
> {"a"=>2, "d"=>5, "f"=>1, "g"=>1, "h"=>1, "i"=>1, "z"=>2}.inject('') {|s,v| s << "#{v.join}"}
 => "a2d5f1g1h1i1z2"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>> {"a"=>2, "d"=>5, "f"=>1, "g"=>1, "h"=>1, "i"=>1, "z"=>2}.flatten.join
=> "a2d5f1g1h1i1z2"
```